# Ubuntu doesn't switch audio outputs properly

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, 19.10

For a few days, my Ubuntu 19.10 desktop keeps reverting to the HDMI output as default audio device even though I set it to Line Out, and I have to manually change it whenever I connect a USB headset where it used to be automatic.

I don't remember exactly when it started happening so I have no ideas what might be causing this, any ideas?

Comment: please specify which Ubuntu version you are using

Comment: @cmak.fr Sorry, it's Ubuntu 19.10, just edited